# Translating analogWrite() into PWM duty cycle formula

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

We can use the function `analogWrite(int x)` for digital pins which support PWM because any microcontroller has a built in PWM generator.For given `x` and for Arduino Uno which is the formula to calculate the duty cycle of the generated PWM signal?Thanks

Comment: x/255 (Now padding up to 30 characters....)

Answer (score 4):

On pins 5 and 6 (those controlled by Timer 0):

- duty cycle = (x+1)/256,
  except for x = 0, which gives a duty cycle of 0.

On the other PWM pins:

- duty cycle = x/255

The difference comes from the fact that Timer 0, which provides the
timing for `millis()`, `micros()` and `delay()`, is configured in “fast
PWM” mode, while the other timers are in “phase correct PWM”

Answer (score 0):

Duty Cycle= (x/255)×100%

x is the value passed to the analogWrite() function, ranging from 0 to 255.
Duty Cycle is expressed as a percentage, representing the fraction of time the signal is on compared to the total period of the PWM signal.

Comment: Not on all pins. Try `analogWrite(5, 1)` on an Uno and see what comes out.